# Display stretched material apply on SCNGeometrySource node

Tags: ios, swift, scenekit, augmented-reality, arkit

I have created SCNNode using Custom selected SCNVector3 points more than three using SCNGeometrySource and apply image material to display very stretched material. How to apply properly material on  SCNGeometrySource node.

```
func getsquareDrawnLineFrom(pos1: SCNVector3,
                            pos2: SCNVector3,
                            pos3: SCNVector3) -> SCNNode {

    let square = SquareplanlineFrom(vector1: pos1, vector2: pos2, vector3: pos3)
    //SCNGeometrySource.Semantic.texcoord
    //SCNGeometrySource.Semantic.normal
    let material = SCNMaterial()
    // material.diffuse.contents = UIColor.lightGray
    material.diffuse.contents = UIImage(named: "grid")
    material.diffuse.contentsTransform = SCNMatrix4MakeScale(32, 32, 0)
    material.diffuse.wrapS = .repeat
    material.diffuse.wrapT = .repeat
    square.materials = [material]
    let square1 = SCNNode(geometry: square)
    square1.name = "tringle"
    return square1
}

// get line geometry between two vectors
func SquareplanlineFrom(vector1: SCNVector3,
              vector2: SCNVector3, vector3: SCNVector3) -> SCNGeometry {
     let normalsPerFace = 3
    let indices: [Int32] = [0, 1, 2]
    let source = SCNGeometrySource(vertices: [vector1, vector2, vector3])
    let normals:[SCNVector3] = [
        vector1,
        vector2,
        vector3].map{[SCNVector3](repeating:$0,count:normalsPerFace)}.flatMap{$0}
    let normalSource = SCNGeometrySource(normals: normals)
    let cgp1 = CGPoint(x: CGFloat(vector1.x), y: CGFloat(vector1.y))
    let cgp2 = CGPoint(x: CGFloat(vector2.x), y: CGFloat(vector2.y))
    let cgp3 = CGPoint(x: CGFloat(vector3.x), y: CGFloat(vector3.y))
    let textcoord = SCNGeometrySource(textureCoordinates: [cgp1,cgp2,cgp3])

    // let texcoord = SCNGeometrySource(textureCoordinates: [])
    // let normalSource = SCNGeometrySource(normals: [vector1, vector2, vector3])

    let element = SCNGeometryElement(indices: indices,
                                     primitiveType: .triangles)
    return SCNGeometry(sources: [source,normalSource,textcoord], elements: [element])
}
```

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### Texture's scale issue:

I don't know the size of your model but I think the problem is – you increased a scale although you have to decrease it to properly map a texture.

[image]

> My texture's size is 2K square (2048x2048, 72dpi).

Here's a code (I used macOS version here):

```
internal func getFaceDrawnFrom(pos1: SCNVector3,
                               pos2: SCNVector3,
                               pos3: SCNVector3) -> SCNNode {

    let triGeo = generateGeoFrom(vector1: pos1,
                                 vector2: pos2,
                                 vector3: pos3)

    let material = SCNMaterial()
    material.diffuse.contents = NSImage.Name("art.scnassets/jaguar.jpg")

    // your scale
    // material.diffuse.contentsTransform = SCNMatrix4MakeScale(32, 32, 0)

    material.isDoubleSided = true

    material.diffuse.contentsTransform = .init(
                                     m11: 0.05, m12: 0,    m13: 0,    m14: 0,
                                     m21: 0,    m22: 0.05, m23: 0,    m24: 0,
                                     m31: 0,    m32: 0,    m33: 1,    m34: 0,
                                     m41: 0,    m42: 0,    m43: 0,    m44: 1)
    material.diffuse.wrapS = .repeat
    material.diffuse.wrapT = .repeat
    square.materials = [material]

    let node = SCNNode(geometry: triGeo)
    node.name = "triangularFace"
    scene.rootNode.addChildNode(node)
    return node
}
```

Then:

```
fileprivate func generateGeoFrom(vector1: SCNVector3,
                                 vector2: SCNVector3,
                                 vector3: SCNVector3) -> SCNGeometry {

    let normalsPerFace = 3
    let indices: [Int32] = [0, 1, 2]
    let source = SCNGeometrySource(vertices: [vector1, vector2, vector3])

    let vecs = [vector1, vector2, vector3].map { 
        [SCNVector3](repeating: $0, count: normalsPerFace) 
    }.flatMap { $0 }

    let normals: [SCNVector3] = vecs

    let normalSource = SCNGeometrySource(normals: normals)
    let cgp1 = CGPoint(x: CGFloat(vector1.x), y: CGFloat(vector1.y))
    let cgp2 = CGPoint(x: CGFloat(vector2.x), y: CGFloat(vector2.y))
    let cgp3 = CGPoint(x: CGFloat(vector3.x), y: CGFloat(vector3.y))
    let textcoord = SCNGeometrySource(textureCoordinates: [cgp1, cgp2, cgp3])
        
    let element = SCNGeometryElement(indices: indices,
                               primitiveType: .triangles)

    return SCNGeometry(sources: [source, normalSource, textcoord], 
                      elements: [element])
}
```

Then let's call the method.

```
let instance = getFaceDrawnFrom(pos1: SCNVector3(x: 0, y: 0, z: 0),
                                pos2: SCNVector3(x: 8, y: 5, z: 0),
                                pos3: SCNVector3(x:-8, y: 5, z: 0))
```

### Normals' direction issue

Usually a model has 3 normals per each triangular face, or in other words, one normal at each vertex of every face. Normals must be perpendicular to a surface, not parallel. If you have issues with surface normals, then you won't be able to light the model.

[image]

Comment: Hello ARGeo, Please Help me, I have setup "allowsCameraControl = true" in Sceneview How to disabled some default functionality. 
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57476065/how-to-off-pan-with-two-fingers-to-translate-the-camera-in-scenekit-swift