# How to disabled some default functionality in Scene view when allowsCameraControl = true?

Tags: swift, scenekit, arkit

Please Help me, I have setup "allowsCameraControl = true" in Scene view. How to disabled some default functionality.
 **Ex** : Pan with two fingers to translate the camera on its local xy-plane

```
 scnview.allowsCameraControl = true
 scnview.defaultCameraController.interactionMode = .orbitTurntable
 scnview.defaultCameraController.inertiaEnabled = true
 scnview.defaultCameraController.maximumVerticalAngle = 69
 scnview.defaultCameraController.minimumVerticalAngle = -69
 scnview.autoenablesDefaultLighting = true
```

Comment: removed extra spaces

Comment: @KalpeshPrajapati, What you call `default functionality`? Could you show more code?

Comment: Setup 
"allowsCameraControl = true " then auto enable below functionality.

1. Pan with one finger to rotate the camera around the scene
2. Pan with two fingers to translate the camera on its local xy-plane
3. Pan with three fingers vertically to move the the camera forward backward
4. Double-tap to switch to the next camera in the scene
5. Rotate with two fingers to roll the camera (rotate on the camera node's z-axis)
6. Pinch to zoom in or zoom out (change the camera's fieldOfView)

Answer (score 3):

You can disable/modify or add more recognisers after setting `allowsCameraControl = true`.

```
if let recognizers = scnview.gestureRecognizers {  
        for gestureRecognizer in recognizers {
            if let gesture = gestureRecognizer as? UIPanGestureRecognizer {
                gestureRecognizer.isEnabled = false
            }
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

To block some gestures used in build-in camera controller:

> - pan with 1 finger to rotate the camera around the scene
> - pan with 2 fingers to translate the camera on its local X,Y plan
> - pan with 3 fingers vertically to move the the camera forward/backward

You can change cameraControlConfiguration sensitivity properties. In your case it is gonna be 'panSensitivity'. But I would recommend to block 'truckSensitivity' too.

```
scnview.cameraControlConfiguration.panSensitivity = 0
```

Answer (score -1):

Look at SCNCameraControlConfiguration (https://developer.apple.com/documentation/scenekit/scncameracontrolconfiguration)

It has some variables for controlling the default camera behavior.  It particular there is a "allowsTranslation" variable that controls two finger panning.

That said, I've had mixed results using this to control the behavior.

Comment: How can I use this property? I couldn't find how to set it.

Comment: You get the SCNView an access the cameraControlConfiguration property.  That object has the settings.

Comment: This configuration is read-only: `open var cameraControlConfiguration: SCNCameraControlConfiguration { get }`