# How to use SCNSceneSource.LoadingOption.createNormalsIfAbsent?

Tags: swift, scenekit

How to use SCNSceneSource.LoadingOption.createNormalsIfAbsent?

The file prim.scn has a simple toroid geometry that has no normals.  When I load and inspect it it still has no normals.  I've also tried with an empty SCNGeometrySource for normals.  It doesn't add them.

```
scnScene = SCNScene()
let documentsPath = FileManager.default.urls(for: .documentDirectory, 
                                              in: .userDomainMask).first!
let url = documentsPath.appendingPathComponent("prim.scn")

do {
    scnScene = try SCNScene(url: url,
                        options: [.createNormalsIfAbsent: true])
} catch {
    print("error")
}
```

Inspecting in lldb yields:

```
(lldb) p scnScene.rootNode.childNodes[3].geometry?.sources
([SCNGeometrySource]?) $R1 = 1 value {
  [0] = 0x0000600001a09f80
}
(lldb) p scnScene.rootNode.childNodes[3].geometry?.sources[0]
(SCNGeometrySource?) $R2 = 0x0000600001a09f80 {
  baseNSObject@0 = {
    isa = SCNGeometrySource
  }
  _data = 0x00007fdef1847c00 4800 bytes
  _semantic = 0x00007ff9540c3ec0 "kGeometrySourceSemanticVertex"
  _vectorCount = 400
  _componentType = 1
  _componentCount = 3
  _colorSpace = 0x0000000000000000
  _dataOffset = 0
  _dataStride = 12
  _mkSemantic = '\0'
  _mtlBuffer = 0x0000000000000000
  _mtlVertexFormat = 0
  _encodeDataAsHalf = '\0'
}
```

I would expect there to be a

```
scnScene.rootNode.childNodes[3].geometry?.sources[0]
```

containing the normals.

Here's [prim.scn](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1Lz7yxxpDpTxfLbNGfbCteEBk_jyP04TZ/view?usp=sharing) file.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You already got info about normals count in your model. The names of parameters are `_vectorCount` and `_componentCount`. Use the following code to calculate the number of [normals](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/scenekit/scnmaterial/1462542-normal). For additional info, read [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56766516/display-stretched-material-apply-on-scngeometrysource-node/56767854#56767854).

***macOS 13.0 Ventura, Xcode 14.1 RC 2***.

```
import SceneKit

class ViewController : UIViewController {

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        
        let sceneView = self.view as! SCNView
        sceneView.autoenablesDefaultLighting = true
        sceneView.backgroundColor = .black

        let path = FileManager.default.urls(for: .documentDirectory,
                                             in: .userDomainMask).first!
        let url = path.appendingPathComponent("prim.scn")

        do {
            let scene = try SCNScene(url: url,
                                 options: [.createNormalsIfAbsent: true])
            sceneView.scene = scene

            let sceneNodes: [SCNNode] = scene.rootNode.childNodes

            for s in (sceneNodes[3].geometry?.sources.enumerated())! {
                // 1200 normals (400 vectors * 3 normals)
                print(s.element.vectorCount * s.element.componentsPerVector)
            }
        } catch {
            print(error.localizedDescription)
        }            
    }
}
```

P. S.

Your model initially has normals – that's why `[.createNormalsIfAbsent: true]` has no effect.

SceneKit's directional light wouldn't work without normals.

[image]

Comment: I'm not seeing what you wrote as being the answer to my question.  What am I missing?  Printing out the number of normals isn't telling me what setting options: [.createNormalsIfAbsent: true] is supposed to do.  If I set it false the prim is still rendered correctly (i.e. makes no discernible difference).  I would expect if set to true that there would be a second source generated as in: scnScene.rootNode.childNodes[3].geometry?.sources[1] with _semantic = "kGeometrySourceSemanticNormal". My question specifically concerns the option .createNormalsIfAbsent and if it actually does anything.

Comment: Many parameters in SceneKit are hard to test empirically, and `.createNormalsIfAbsent` is just such a parameter. If your model doesn't have normals, then `.createNormalsIfAbsent = true` creates 3 normals per each triangular face (one normal at each vertex of this face). But if the normals do already exist, then this parameter is not taken into account.

Comment: The sample I provided a link to in my question is missing the normals and it doesn't seem to create them.  At least it doesn't create a source for them.  It seems that this parameter doesn't do anything.  If you can confirm I will accept the answer as a Apple bug.

Comment: I made changes to my answer.

Comment: What I think you are showing is the single source for the geometry vertices (positions) not the normals.  If you load the prim.scn in SceneKit and look at scnScene.rootNode.childNodes[3].geometry?.sources you will see one source where as there should be two.  SceneKit is calculating the normals and keeping them somewhere (otherwise the directional light wouldn't work, but it not keeping them in the sources array).   Where can I get see and print the calculated normals?  That said the widget does seem to show a normal but I don't know how you get that widget (maybe because of Xcode version).

Comment: Not all sources are decomposable in SceneKit.